# View Core data stored in mavericks or Yosemite

Tags: database, sqlite, core-data, osx-mavericks

I am creating an app that uses Core data, how can I see the data stored in them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command line tool `sqlite3` included in your Mac. Locate the database by e.g. logging the persistent store url, then just use

```
sqlite3 path/to/database.sqlite
```

Type `.h` to get help on how to use it. You can make standard SQL queries, etc.